# Trunc a number and get removed value. Or cast to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, truncate

I try to get the removed part of the `math.trunc` function.
Or a function supports this request.

```
import math
number = 1.9
newnumber, removed = math.trunc(number)
```

I need the number = `1` and also the removed `0.9`
So basicly i need the integer and the removed float.

Obove example will not work :/
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a handle on the truncated number, and subtract it from the original number:

```
import math
number = 1.9
truncated = math.trunc(number)
print(truncated, number - truncated)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use modf you can flip the order of your variables and get the result you want.

```
import math
number = 1.9
removed, newnumber = math.modf(number)
```

Comment: oh cool i did not know about this :) I love learning new tricks!

Answer (score 1):

For a starting point, use modulus 1 get the removed part.

```
def truncate(n):
    return math.trunc(n), n % 1
```

Then you want to consider how negative numbers are handled. Do they return a positive ‘removed’ value?

This method won’t work for negative numbers, instead you can subtract the truncates number from the original:

```
t = math.trunc(n)
return t, n - t
```

Comment: or just `print("%g %g"%(divmod(1.9,1)))`